# How to remove old lines when new ones heve been drawn?

Tags: processing

I am experienced in Web Development but new to Processing. 
I have come up with a simple sketch that draws some lines, making nice spirograph-like images:

```java
float x1 = random(width);
float y1 = random(height);
float x2 = random(width);
float y2 = random(height);
float speedx1 = random(5,20);
float speedy1 = random(5,20);
float speedx2 = random(5,20);
float speedy2 = random(5,20);

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(0.5);
  frameRate(15);
 }

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    if ((x1 > width) || (x1 < 0)) {
    speedx1 = speedx1 * -1;
    }
    if ((y1 > height) || (y1 < 0)) {
    speedy1 = speedy1 * -1;
    }
    if ((x2 > width) || (x2 < 0)) {
    speedx2 = speedx2 * -1;
    }
    if ((y2 > height) || (y2 < 0)) {
    speedy2 = speedy2 * -1;
    }

    x1 += speedx1; 
    y1 += speedy1; 
    x2 += speedx2; 
    y2 += speedy2; 
    line(x1, y1, x2 ,y2);

   if (frameCount%500 == 0) saveFrame("spirograph-#####.png");
   }
}
```

This is fine, but after a while the image is cluttered with lines because they don't go away. So I'd like to keep some lines (maybe 15) and delete the old ones.

I could of course write the coordinates of the old ones to an array and make a white line of the first element over the black line, then delete the first element of the array and create a new array element at the end. But this would draw white pixels over the newer lines, whic is undesirable.

Is there a way to solve this? 
Maybe create objects that are later being cleared?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to create a class `CLine`, which can holde the coordinates of a line and draw a line:

```java
public class CLine {

    public CLine() {}
    public float _x1 = 0, _y1 = 0, _x2 = 0, _y2 = 0;

    public void set( float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 ) {
        _x1 = x1; _y1 = y1; _x2 = x2; _y2 = y2;
    }

    public void draw() {
        if ( _x1 != _x2 || _y1 != _y2 )
            line(_x1, _y1, _x2 , _y2);
    }
};
```

Create an array of `CLine` objects and initialize it in the the `setup` function:

```java
CLine [] lines;
int current = 0;

void setup() {
    int no_of = 15;
    lines = new CLine[no_of];
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of; ++ i )
        lines[i] = new CLine();

    size(640, 360);
    background(255);
    strokeWeight(0.5);
    frameRate(15);
 }
```

Create a new line in every `draw` and store the coordinates to the array of `CLine` objects. Use a control variable `next_line_index`, to hold the index of the array element where the next line to be stored. If the counter reaches the end of the array, it has to bes et to 0.
Now you can clear the screen in every frame and you can draw all the lines which are stored in the array to a clean view:

```java
float x1 = random(width);
float y1 = random(height);
float x2 = random(width);
float y2 = random(height);
float speedx1 = random(5,20);
float speedy1 = random(5,20);
float speedx2 = random(5,20);
float speedy2 = random(5,20);
```

```java
int next_line_index = 0;
void draw() {

    if ((x1 > width) || (x1 < 0)) {
        speedx1 = speedx1 * -1;
    }
    if ((y1 > height) || (y1 < 0)) {
        speedy1 = speedy1 * -1;
    }
    if ((x2 > width) || (x2 < 0)) {
        speedx2 = speedx2 * -1;
    }
    if ((y2 > height) || (y2 < 0)) {
        speedy2 = speedy2 * -1;
    }

    x1 += speedx1; 
    y1 += speedy1; 
    x2 += speedx2; 
    y2 += speedy2;

    lines[next_line_index++].set(x1, y1, x2, y2 );
    if (next_line_index == lines.length) next_line_index = 0;

    background(255);
    for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; ++ j )
        lines[j].draw();

    if (frameCount%500 == 0) saveFrame("spirograph-#####.png");
}
```

Preview:
[image]

Comment: I get an error: The Variable x1 does not exist in this line:
    if ((x1 > width) || (x1 < 0)) {
Am I missing something?

Comment: @MisterWoyng Of course you have to keep the variable declarations for `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `speedx1`, `speedy1`, `speedx2` and `speedy2` from your question. I added them to the answer.

Comment: Wow...works now and looks great. Thanks a million. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I could of course write the coordinates of the old ones to an array and make a white line of the first element over the black line, then delete the first element of the array and create a new array element at the end. But this would draw white pixels over the newer lines, whic is undesirable.

You're on the right track. You want to store the coordinates of your lines in an array (or better yet, in an ArrayList of `Line` instances). But you don't want to "erase" the lines one at a time.

Instead, you probably want to clear out everything! You can do this by calling the `background()` function. Then redraw the lines that you want.

Here's a very basic example:

```
void draw(){
  background(255);

  for(Line line : lines){
    line.draw();
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  lines.add(new Line(0, 0, mouseX, mouseY));
  if(lines.size() >= 10){
    lines.remove(0);
  }
}
```

This code assumes you've created a `Line` class, but more importantly notice how previous frames are cleared out every time `draw()` is called. This is a very standard approach and is probably what you want to do for most Processing sketches.

Comment: I seem to have difficulties creating a Line class. How would you do that?

Comment: @MisterWoyng Rabbid76's answer already covers that, but you also might want to check out [this tutorial](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) on creating classes in Processing.